# Need to create horizontal tree diagram using jquery or php

Tags: php, jquery, tree, diagram

I not new programmer but I'm badly stuck in this task.The requirement is create tree structure.I know there is lot of plugin can create this easily but there is another thing is level. when user add a node.They can also give level where this node will display. if user add level 2. node have to show on level 2. and there can be more than one parent.

I already created parent and child tree structure with google API or many other js plugin it easily created. but no one plugin give level option with tree structure.

So i think to create own custom script. Please anyone give me any idea how It will possible using jquery or PHP. I also attach images for brief details.
[image]

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: i try from last 2 days. looking many plugin but problem is only level and i need this urgent.

Comment: Your urgency doesn't remove the fact that your question is way too broad for StackOverflow. Please read [how to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I just give my requirement and ask any idea means, give any plugin or any code that can solved my problem.

Comment: That isn't how StackOverflow works @mollie